# Removing duplicates from collection of points, with mapping

Tags: c#, collections

I have an array of points, let's call it rawPoints, which contains duplicates. In fact, almost every point is repeated from 2 to 6 times. Repeated *somewhere*, not in consecutive locations. I want to remove the duplicates to get a new collection, which I'll call goodPoints. Also, **I want to know the mapping from rawPoints to goodPoints. In other words, for each point P in rawPoints, I want to know the (unique) index i such that goodPoints[i] = P.**

I'm coding in C#, so I'm wondering if any of the .NET collections will help with this.

I've read that using a HashSet is a good way to remove duplicates. But that won't give me the mapping.

One possible solution is an "AddorFind(P)" function that I can use to add a point P to goodPoints. If P is not yet a member of goodPoints, then AddorFind(P) will add it. If P is already a member of goodPoints, then AddorFind(P) will return an index i such that goodPoints[i] = P.

Does something like that exist, or is there some other simple and reasonably fast solution?

Comment: Is `rawPoints` ordered so that identical points are together, or are they mixed up?

Comment: Why do you need the unique index? It looks like you simply want to operate on non-duplicate points.

Comment: @MatthewWatson -- Mixed up

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov -- I have data structures that reference members of rawPoints. I want to change them to reference indices into goodPoints. Make sense?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you're trying to do. Is there a particular reason you have to know the index into `rawPoints`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov -- I need the indices into goodPoints, because that's what I want to store in my data structures. I'm converting "triangle soup" into a mesh in which each triangle contains 3 vertex indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two outputs:

1. The "good points" list.
2. An array of indices into the good points array which is the same length as the raw points (since you want to map every raw point index into the good point array).

I think this code will generate those two things:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var rawPoints = createRandomPoints(10000, 100, 100);

            int[] goodPointMap = new int[rawPoints.Length];
            var map = new Dictionary<Point, int>();
            var goodPoints = new List<Point>();

            for (int i = 0; i < rawPoints.Length; ++i)
            {
                Point p = rawPoints[i];
                int index;

                if (map.TryGetValue(p, out index))
                {
                    goodPointMap[i] = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    map[p] = goodPoints.Count;
                    goodPointMap[i] = goodPoints.Count;
                    goodPoints.Add(p);
                }
            }

            // At this point we no longer need 'map', which is used only to generate 'goodPoints[]'
            // and 'goodPointMap[]'.

            Console.WriteLine("Number of good points = " + goodPoints.Count);

            // Every point in rawPoints[] should have a point in goodPoints
            // which you can reference via goodPointMap[].
            // Let's verify that:

            for (int i = 0; i < rawPoints.Length; ++i)
                if (rawPoints[i] != goodPoints[goodPointMap[i]])
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
        }

        static Point[] createRandomPoints(int n, int maxX, int maxY)
        {
            var rng    = new Random();
            var result = new Point[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                result[i] = new Point(rng.Next(maxX), rng.Next(maxY));

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks good. This appears to be the same algorithm suggested by @dasblinkenlight. Is that true? The code is very helpful, even if it is the same algorithm.

Comment: @bubba It's probably very similar. I didn't read his answer because I was busy writing this one. :) By the way, the line `if (map.TryGetValue(p, out index))` is an amortized O(1) operation, so the loop should be O(N) overall.

Comment: Hmm on closer inspection, my answer is slightly different because I'm using a separate goodPointMap[] array to map from rawPoint[] indices to goodPoint[] indices.

Answer (score 3):

Although `HashSet<Point>` will not help finding a unique index in `goodPoints`, a `Dictionary<Point,int>` would.

In addition to a `List<Point> goodPoints`, make a dictionary `Dictionary<Point,int> mappings` that maps points to an index in `goodPoints` list. When you go through `rawPoints` array, follow this algorithm:

- Check if `rawPoints[i]` is in `mappings`. If it is, continue to next point
- Otherwise, add the current length of `goodPoints` to `mappings` for  `rawPoints[i]`, and then add  `rawPoints[i]` to the `gooodPoints` list.

Assuming that your `Point` representation has a good hash function, and also that it overrides `Equals` properly, this algorithm produces both a list of `goodPoints` and a mapping in O(N).

Comment: Thanks. This looks a lot more promising than the other answers. Is there, perhaps, a typo? You wrote "add rawPoints[i] to the gooodPoints length". How do I add a point to a length? Did you mean "add rawPoints[i] to the gooodPoints array."

Comment: I'm a bit worried about "Check if rawPoints[i] is in mappings". Isn't that an O(N) operation. If so, then the total process is O(N^2), isn't it?

Comment: @bubba No, since `mappings` is a `Dictionary<Point,int>`, a hash-based container, a lookup runs in O(1).

Comment: @bubba Yes, "length" should be "list" (edited). I used a list instead of an array so that I could add items to it without worrying about their count. If you need an array, call `ToArray` on the list at the end to convert your list to an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using Linq:

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
points.Add(new Point(1, 1));
points.Add(new Point(1, 1));
points.Add(new Point(1, 1));
points.Add(new Point(1, 2));
points.Add(new Point(1, 2));
points.Add(new Point(1, 2));

List<Point> goodPoints = new List<Point>();


foreach (Point p in points)
{
    goodPoints.Add(p);
    //goodPoints = goodPoints.Distinct().ToList();
    //int idx = goodPoints.IndexOf(p);
    int idx = (goodPoints = goodPoints.Distinct().ToList()).IndexOf(p);
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Index of Point({0}, {1}) = {2}", p.X, p.Y, idx));
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to count the unique number of elements. Also, `Select(x => x)` is completely redundant.

Comment: The count is just to show the number of unique items, he would still have access to a new list of distinct points.

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers the OP's requirement to keep an index into the old list with duplicates?

Comment: How does this give me the mapping from rawPoints to goodPoints? In other words, given a point P in rawPoints, how do I find the index i such that goodPoints[i] = P ?

Comment: Modified, just add the point to the good list and then reset the list to the unique of itself and return `IndexOf(Point)`.

Comment: Something like this is the first thing that occured to me. First get the unique set of points, and then use IndexOf to build the map. It seemed to me that Distinct and IndexOf contain a lot of common logic, since they are both essentially hunting through the collection looking for points. So, I thought some hunting would be done twice. Was looking for better efficiency.

Comment: @bubba You can examine all of this using ILSpy. `List<T>.IndexOf()` uses the `IndexOf()` on `System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`, which loops through the array until it find the correct item, pretty straight forward. `Distinct` on `System.Linq.Enumerable` uses `DistinctIterator`, which loops through the collection and tries to add each item to a `Set<T>` which is a very simplified version of `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PointComparer class an use it in Distinct method.

```
public class PointComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{
    public bool Equals(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return p1.x==p2.x && p1.y == p2.y;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Point p1)
    {
        return p1.x*p2.x;//bla bla
    }
}
```

And

```
goodPoints = rawPoints.Distinct(new PointComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I assumed I would have to write custom "compare" or "equality" functions. Given a point P in rawPoints, how does your code tell me the corresponding index i in goodPoints (i.e. the index i such that goodPoints[i] = P) ??